# c program ignores all scanfs after wrong variable type input

Tags: c, validation, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

   int a, b, checka, checkb;

   printf ("enter a: ");
   checka = scanf ("%d", &a);

   printf ("enter b: ");
   checkb = scanf ("%d", &b);

   printf ("checka = %d\n", checka);
   printf ("checkb = %d", checkb);



   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I was having this problem in a larger program but I wrote a quick test to see if I could fix it, which I can't.

Basically when anything other than an integer is entered for a scanf, the program just instantly skips and ignores every other scanf and just prints the rest of the program it sees, meaning I can't make checks with a while loop, or I just get an infinite loop as the scanf in the loop to fix the variable just gets skipped.

Obviously if integers are entered this particular program will just return 1 for the last two printfs, which is expected.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a reason to check the return value od `scanf`. It is there for reason.

Comment: Is that not what I am doing already?

Comment: No, I don't see any check here, you are just printing the results

Comment: ahh, after reading the answer below I understand what a check is now Eugene, thanks.

Comment: A new programmer who observes the results of `scanf()`! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason why we should check scanf for errors, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int a, b, checka, checkb;

    printf ("enter a: ");
    if((scanf ("%d", &a)) == 1){
        checka = a;
    }else{
        printf("Error(1)!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    printf ("enter b: ");
    if((scanf ("%d", &b)) == 1){
        checkb = b;
    }else{
        printf("Error(2)!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("checka = %d\n", checka);
    printf ("checkb = %d", checkb);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea the initial scanf has to be the condition of the if statement, cheers!

Comment: @Lewisss Always check scanf (and its family) for Errors.